# Update 1 in 4 boolean fields in a single table

Tags: ms-access, boolean

I have a badly designed table containing 4 boolean fields, and only one of these 4 fields needs to be true. 
ATM i'm just trying to generate random data for testing, but I'm unable to find a way to randomly set one of the four fields to true for 10000 rows. 
Is there any pure SQL way to this or should I use some VBA code to do this?
The database I have to use is Microsoft Access.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT - based on Hmax's answer**

```
Private Sub UpdateRandomColumns_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rdm As Integer
    Dim tab(1 To 4) As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Data")
    '4 columns that need to randomly be updated per row
    tab(1) = "TimeOut"
    tab(2) = "Interaction"
    tab(3) = "Responses"
    tab(4) = "Manual"

    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rdm = Int((4 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        rs(aray(rdm)) = True
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    MsgBox("Update successful")
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried looping 10,000 times, inserting on each loop. Generate a random number from 1 to 4 at the start of each loop and add a condition where depending on the random number you set the corresponding field to true?

Comment: @Hmax checks Edit in post for a simpler version of your comment (no "if" required) :) thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your UPDATE SQL a VBA function like this:

```
Public Function Random1of4(varID As Variant, intIndex As Integer) As Boolean
    Static curID As Variant
    Static intVal As Integer
    If curID <> varID Then
        'new id, generate new random number from 1 to 4
        intVal = Int(Rnd * 4 + 1)
        curID = varID
    End If
    Random1of4 = intIndex = intVal
End Function
```

This function uses static variables, which keep values between function calls. It internally generates new random number from 1 to 4 (intVal) and returns True if intIndex parameter is equal to intVal. New intVal generated if parameter varID changed.
Create this function in standard module, then create and run UPDATE statement with this function - pass to varID any value from table, which is different for every row (normally primary key) and to intIndex a number from 1 to 4 for each of boolean fields:

```
UPDATE Data
SET  TimeOut = Random1of4([ID], 1)
    ,Interaction = Random1of4([ID], 2)
    ,Responses = Random1of4([ID], 3)
    ,Manual = Random1of4([ID], 4);
```

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understant your answer, so i went with a simpler version of @Hmax 's answer

Comment: I added some comments and edited the answer, it should be more clear now. This technique allows to create SQL statements with tricky additional functionality. It would be great to compare performance of this solution and @Hmax answer. Normally SQL works faster than Recordset loop.